# jQuery Mobile Button Alignment in List Divider

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a jQuery mobile app and was wondering if anyone could help with button alignment within a list divider. Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/671/) to a jsFiddle I created showing the button next to the text. I was wondering if it was possible to align the button to the right. I've tried adding a div around the button with a style of `style="text-align: right;"`, but that pushes the button down like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/673/), which I don't want.

Is there anyway to keep the text and the button on the same line, with the button aligned to the right? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/676/

Comment: It does align the button to the right, but I also would like the `List Header` text to be aligned on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it by using a 2 column [layout grid](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-grids.html), see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrJrK/1/)

code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
    <div  data-role="header"><h1>Header Page 1</h1></div>

    <div  data-role="content">
         <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
           <li data-role="list-divider">
             <div class="ui-bar ui-grid-a">
               <div class="ui-block-a" style="margin-top:10px;">List Header</div>
               <div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align:right;"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="plus" data-inline="true" data-theme="a">Add</a></div>
             </div>
           </li>
           <li>List item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div  data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div>
</div>
```

screenhsot:
[image]

Comment: That looks pretty good! I think it will do for now. Any idea on how to keep that black header the same size? (It seems to have expanded vertically compared to this origina jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/671/) Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I removed the `ui-bar` class from the div wrapper and it shrunk as I wanted. Much thanks!